# How to properly stub methods on a different thread using OCMock?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I have the following unit test that is failing. I think its because `OCMock` does not work well across multiple threads but I could be wrong. `mockTestMethodA` never gets called. If I modified the code to call the `testMethodA` on the same thread (without `NSThread`), stubbing seems to work. Is this a known limitation of `OCMock` or am I missing something?

Sample code:

```
- (void) testCallMethodUsingNSThreadFromADifferentClass
{
   mockTestClassA = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:testClassA];

   [[[mockTestClassA expect] andCall:@selector(mockTestMethodA) onObject:self] testMethodA];

   [testClassC threadedRequestToCallMethodA];

   [self waitForCompletion:5.0];

   [mockTestClassA verify];
}
```

`threadedRequestToCallMethodA` and `callMethodAFromTestClassC` in `TestClassC` are defined as follows:

```
- (void) threadedRequestToCallMethodA
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(callMethodAFromTestClassC) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void) callMethodAFromTestClassC
{
    [[[TestClassA alloc] init] testMethodA];
}
```

`testMethodA` in `TestClassA` is defined as:

```
- (void) testMethodA
{
    NSLog(@"testMethodA");
}
```

Stub method is defined as follows:

```
- (void) mockTestMethodA
{
   NSLog(@"mockTestMethodA");
}
```

And finally `waitForCompletion`:

```
- (BOOL) waitForCompletion:(NSTimeInterval)timeoutSecs
{
    NSDate  *timeoutDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeoutSecs];
    do {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:timeoutDate];
        if([timeoutDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0.0)
        break;
    } while (!done);

   return done;
 }
```

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you aren't calling the test method on the object you partially mocked, but are instead alloc'ing a new one in your `callMethodAFromTestClassC`. If you call it on the proper object, it works fine. See below (note I don't actually create a separate class C, but the effect is the same). As a side note, I think blocks and GCD make life easier, but everyone has their own style.

```
//
//  TestClassTest.m
//  TestApp
//
//  Created by Benjamin Flynn on 11/20/12.
//

#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>
#import "OCMock.h"
#import "TestClassA.h"

@interface TestClassTest : SenTestCase

@property (nonatomic, retain) TestClassA *testClassA;
@property (atomic, assign) BOOL done;
@end


@implementation TestClassTest

- (void) testCallMethodUsingNSThreadFromADifferentClass
{
    self.testClassA = [[TestClassA alloc] init];
    id mockTestClassA = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:self.testClassA];
    [[[mockTestClassA expect] andCall:@selector(mockTestMethodA) onObject:self] testMethodA];
    [self threadedRequestToCallMethodA];
    [self waitForCompletion:5.0];    
    [mockTestClassA verify];
}

- (void)threadedRequestToCallMethodA
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(callMethodAFromTestClassC) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}


- (void)callMethodAFromTestClassC
{
    [self.testClassA testMethodA];
}

- (void)mockTestMethodA
{
    NSLog(@"Mock test method A");
    self.done = YES;
}

- (BOOL)waitForCompletion:(NSTimeInterval)timeoutSecs
{
    NSDate  *timeoutDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeoutSecs];
    NSLog(@"Starting timer");
    do {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:timeoutDate];
        if([timeoutDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0.0)
            break;
    } while (!self.done);
    NSLog(@"Ending timer");

    return self.done;
}

@end
```